# Find out what exceptions a method throws programmatically

Tags: java, reflection

Imagine you have a method like:

```
public void doGreatThings() throws CantDoGreatThingsException, RuntimeException {...}
```

Is there any way to programmatically get the declared thrown exceptions by way of reflection?

```
// It might return something like Exception[] thrownExceptions = [CantDoGreatThingsException.class, RuntimeException.class]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`getExceptionTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getExceptionTypes--) method. You will not get `Exception[]` since such array would expect exception *instances*, but you will get instead `Class<?>[]` which will hold all thrown exception `.class`.

Demo:

```
class Demo{
    private void test() throws IOException, FileAlreadyExistsException{}

    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method declaredMethod = Demo.class.getDeclaredMethod("test");
        Class<?>[] exceptionTypes = declaredMethod.getExceptionTypes();
        for (Class<?> exception: exceptionTypes){
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class java.io.IOException
class java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that the reflection api.

```
// First resolve the method
Method method = MyClass.class.getMethod("doGreatThings");
// Retrieve the Exceptions from the method
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(method.getExceptionTypes()));
```

if the method requires parameters you need to supply them with the Class.getMethod() call.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public void test() throws RuntimeException, IOException {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("test").getExceptionTypes()));
    }

}
```